# Refilling gravel under slab on a downhill grade

Tags: concrete, slab, grading

Our front patio was poured over an existing slab, with a significant gravel layer between them. I am digging out our water line, which happens to run just outside the edge of the slab. The plywood form which held the gravel is old and falling apart as we dig, resulting in gravel falling out, as there is a downhill grade on that side of the slab.

Once I'm done with this project and start filling dirt back in, how can I replace the gravel under the slab? With the grade I'm afraid it's just going to keep falling out.

[image: Opening under slab]

Answer (score 3):

You don't replace the gravel, you use a flowable fill (kinda like grout).  I would do it in stages with wood forms to keep the flowfill in place (vertically flush with the slab), then backfill the soil afterward.

Comment: Can you recommend a DIY flowable fill? To make sure I'm using the right sort of product?

Comment: @nickwesselman Honestly, in your situation, I'd just get a bag or two of basic Sakrete high-strength and mix some of it up.  If you mix it up and it doesn't have much slump, just add a little water until it kinda plops to fill the space when you dump it in the hole.  Sorry, that's not very precise, but it's all I've got.  Concrete can be a little bit of a "wing it" deal with how much water to add.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I have is to use a closed cell spray foam insulation like [Froth-Pak](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FROTH-PAK-200-Spray-Foam-Sealant-Kit-656-oz-12031949/316253042) to fill in the gap under the slab.

Inspiration from [this DIY video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLbPWc43BjI&t=328s).

EDIT: But kind of expensive

Comment: You don't need to denote your edits. They're all in the log. Just update your answer as you like. Complete sentences are best.

Comment: Unless that spray foam is designed for structural use, I wouldn't use it. Remember, that gravel was supporting this corner of the concrete. Do you want to rely on some foam to support weight?

Answer (score 0):

As I started backfilling dirt from this project, I realized I could backfill the gravel as well with a bit of patience. I used a plywood form at the start to allow me to get a base of gravel under the slab. Then I used a ram I built from a stake and a 2x4 to progressively push in layers of wet gravel/sand, and built up the dirt as I went. The gravel extended beyond the slab but seemed packed in well under it. Then I layered dirt on top and tamped it down.

[image: backfilling gravel]

[image: my diy ram]

Either it will work or I will be mudjacking this corner in the future.